# Error: "Smalltalk / V" "Virtual machine stack overflow" when I try to access application

Tags: stack-overflow, vmware, smalltalk

We have an application called Labware LIMS which is developed with SmallTalk. It is installed on a virtual server (VMware) with OS Windows Server Standard SP2.

Problem: When attempting to enter remote access to the application or from the server itself, a small window "Smalltalk / V" "Virtual machine stack overflow".

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSjiQ.png)

The provider says he has not had problems at other facilities, so let us think that must be some server settings in the VMware system or on the same server.

I appreciate all the help offered.

Comment: Is there an error.log file in the application directory?

Comment: Nauta69, your question provides insufficient information for anyone to respond. This is also not the place to report issues with Smalltalk products. You should contact Labware instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After revisions, we come to the solution. It was the user did not have permissions on a user's folder on the server where the application writes information concerning what has been done by each connected user. coopropietario permissions to the folder the user is then granted, and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to log in to the application from remote computer, it creates a folder in C drive on the application server with remote computer name. On that folder you need to provide the permissions to users who are tyring to access from remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is quite in the past already.
But I just want to share to other small group who are still using smalltak labware lims with the version 7 as I have also experienced the pain.

[Issue]: Since labware was slow I was impatient, I kill the program via the task manager. I ended up with this issue:Smalltalk/V Virtual machine stack overflow. Request a WER dump? Yes/No (popup)

[Solution]:
My solution if you are using Windows 10/11:

1. Go to your yourDrive:Program Files (x86)<YourLabwareFolder>\Client folder
2. notice that from this folder, you see *.log and .obj files (RunTaskInfo.obj, EN_NLS.obj) with your current date (date when you run this program), cut and paste this to your temp folder.
3. Run again your labware.

This small quick fix have solved my issue. I hope this helps.